# Visual Studio LibXL error "Unable to start program 'C:\...\ConsoleApplication\x64\Debug\ExcelTest.exe'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libxl

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios to create a C++ program that interacts (read/writes) with Excel through LibXL, and I'm experiencing start-up errors when running my program.

I followed [these steps](https://www.libxl.com/vscpp.html) to set-up my LibXL repository and directories like the steps posted, and every time I run the program it immediately halts and I'm presented with the white Microsoft Visual Studio Box exclaiming:
"Unable to start program 'C:------\Documents\ConsoleApplication\x64\Debug\ExcelTest.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified."
Obviously the message is referring to not being able to find my program because of the path library or directories... but I have tried rebuilding, restarting, and other troubleshooting and can't seem to get past this message. How can I resolve this, or is there another way I can interface with Excel?

I've tried rebuilding the solution, restarting VS, remaking my program and path libraries. None of which worked and got me past the error code.

Comment: Have you tried starting it from the command line after navigating to the place where the exe is located? That way you might get a little bit more information. I suspect it can't find a required DLL but is being rather vague about it. An earlier version of 2022 would sometimes lock up on me when starting a debug session once in a blue moon with 100% cpu usage and no output but a patch last year seems to have fixed that.

Comment: @MartinBrown After going into command prompt and changing into the correct directory for the project, it wasn't letting me run the program out of command prompt. I was met with a "----- is not recognized as an internal or external command. So I then put command "dir" in the directory and the 5 files created for the project by Visual Studio are there, but no .exe. So somewhere along the line, the executable for my program is not being sent or created to the right place?... or at all?

Comment: There should be an error message hiding in some build progress window or other then. Failure to build the executable at all explains why it fails "file not found".

Comment: Are you sure the build succeeded? There's normally a message to tell you that the build failed and do you want to launch the executable anyway but you can disable it. If you've disabled that message you should reenable it